# Scheme procedure problem

Tags: scheme, sicp

I defined the Scheme procedure to return another procedure with 2 parameters :

```
(define (smooth f)
  (λ(x dx)(/ (+ (f (- x dx))
             (f x)
             (f (+ x dx)))
          3.0)))
```

if i run this procedure with sin procedure with 2 arguments 10 and 0.0001 then it is ok

```
  ((smooth sin) 10 0.0001) ==> -0.544021109075966
```

if i run this procedure recursively, then it has error

```
((smooth (smooth sin)) 10 0.0001)
==> procedure expects 2 arguments, given 1: #<promise:temp6>
```

So can anyone tell me where is my problem? 
Thank you in advance !!!

PS:this is apart of exercise 1.44 in SICP

Comment: ((smooth ((smooth sin) 10 0.0001)) 10 0.0001)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty simple, the result of `(smooth sin)` is a 2-argument procedure which becomes the F in the outer SMOOTH, and F is applied to only one value.

The solution is to make the result of SMOOTH a 1-argument procedure instead, then you can apply it repeatedly.